# Which methods to use to display bootstrap modal on incorrect login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, modal-dialog

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AP\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SBAIMS;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from User_Master where UserID='"+userid.Value+"' and Password='"+password.Value+"'",con);
SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adptr.Fill(ds, "User_Master");
if (ds.Tables["User_Master"].Rows.Count > 0)
{

    Session["slogin"] = userid.Value;
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");

}
else
{

}
con.Close();
```

I want to know what to write in else part to redirect the control to href=retrylogin, i have created a modal with 'retrylogin' as id of it in Default.aspx page. The above is the cs file of Default.aspx

Thank u very much !!

Comment: Side notes - wrap connection usage in `using` statement. Use SqlCommandParameters for passing parameters to command

Comment: This doesn't look like MVC + your code is not protected against SQL injections.

Comment: @ken2k Thank u. but i'm quiet new to programming. just started. so currently i just want to have the prototype working. i will definitely see to sql injection security in future. Currently i want to know how to transfer control to the modal in the page Default.aspx

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Sir plz elaborate. I am novice. Thank u.!